# Optimal way to sort an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array in the form `[A,B,B,A,A]`. What is the optimized way to sort the array so I get `[A,A,A,B,B]`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) And are you sure you need to optimize this? Have you timed your code?

Comment: You are not happy with Arrays.sort or Collections.sort (in case that array is in a java collection)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array?rq=1 .. not a very good question either, but it provides code on how to sort an array

Answer (score 6):

When you have the the Power bring it to good use... `Why reinvent the wheel ???`

Use  `Arrays.sort()` to **sort the Array.**

**-** If what you hold in the Array is some kind of object and it needs to be sorted in More than One way.... then first convert it in to a ArrayList (or List) using `Arrays.asList(array)`

**Eg:**

```
Song[] dog = new Song[10];
 ArrayList<Song> list = new ArrayList<Song>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Then use `java.util.Comparator` Interface, to sort the Object on basis of more than one attribute.

**Eg:**
          Class Song can be sorted on the basis of its track title or Singer and more using `Comparator` Interface.

**-** Using `Collections` are **lot more flexible** than `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickSort) or [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort)
if you want to implement fast sorting on your own.

Otherwise use the built in java sort functions.

Comment: (Why would the Java built-in sort implementations not use these "advanced sorting techniques"? Manually writing a quick/merge/comb sort implementation is an interesting exercise, but often nothing more.)

Comment: Afaik java uses QuickSort. I just tried to answer the original question "what is the optimized way" and in my opinion the optimized way is using QuickSort or MergeSort - no matter who implemented it.