# Java min max values

Tags: java

Everything is working fine, I just need my output to say the quarter with the highest/lowest rainfall, not the actual values. I am not sure how to tie the quarter and the values together so that the output will be quarter 1, 2, 3 or 4.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rainfall
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      double[] rainfall = new double[4]; 
      double totalRainfall = 0.0; 
      double max = 0, min = 0;


      for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) 
      { 
         System.out.print("Enter rainfall for quarter " + (i+1) + ": "); 
         rainfall[i] = scan.nextDouble(); 
         totalRainfall += rainfall[i]; 
         if (i == 0)
         {
            max = min = rainfall[i];
         }

         {
            if (rainfall[i] > max)
               max = rainfall[i];
            else if (rainfall[i] < min)
               min = (i + 1);
            //min = rainfall[i];     
         }
     }

   System.out.println("Total rainfall = "+totalRainfall); 
   System.out.println("Average rainfall = "+(totalRainfall / 4.0)); 
   System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ max);
   System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + min);

   //System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ maxQuarter);
   //System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + minQuarter);

   }//end main 
}//end class
```

Comment: Sort that array and print the first/last value of the array.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array

Answer (score 2):

Just store the indexes instead of the values:

```
if (rainfall[i] > rainfall[max])
    max = i;
else if (rainfall[i] < rainfall[min])
    min = i;

System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = " + max + 1);
System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + min + 1);
```

Comment: Should be i + 1, since the indexes will be 0 to 3 but they want them to correspond to quarters 1 to 4. Or they can add the 1 on when they output.

Comment: Ah good point, and I agree that that should go in the print statement.

Comment: How would i declare the min and max at the top of the code?  Sorry, I am extremely new to java

Comment: You could initialize them as 0 (like you have done).  This would mean that the min and max would default to the first quarter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to track maxQuarter and minQuarter (added as ints) as well as max and min. Like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rainfall
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      double[] rainfall = new double[4]; 
      double totalRainfall = 0.0; 
      double max = 0, min = 0;
      // init to Q1 as that's the 1st tested
      int maxQuarter = 1, minQuarter = 1;


      for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) 
      { 
         System.out.print("Enter rainfall for quarter " + (i+1) + ": "); 
         rainfall[i] = scan.nextDouble(); 
         totalRainfall += rainfall[i]; 
         if (i == 0)
         {
            max = min = rainfall[i];
         }

         {
            if (rainfall[i] > max) {
               max = rainfall[i];
               maxQuarter = i + 1;
            }
            if (rainfall[i] < min) {
               min = rainfall[i];
               minQuarter = i + 1;
            }
         }
     }

   System.out.println("Total rainfall = "+totalRainfall); 
   System.out.println("Average rainfall = "+(totalRainfall / 4.0)); 
   System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ max);
   System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + min);

   System.out.println("Max quarter rainfall = "+ maxQuarter);
   System.out.println("Min quarter rainfall = " + minQuarter);

   }//end main 
}//end class
```

With these changes, it runs fine for my basic tests:

```
Enter rainfall for quarter 1: 2
Enter rainfall for quarter 2: 4
Enter rainfall for quarter 3: 6
Enter rainfall for quarter 4: 7
Total rainfall = 19.0
Average rainfall = 4.75
Max quarter rainfall = 7.0
Min quarter rainfall = 2.0
Max quarter rainfall = 4
Minquarter rainfall = 1
```

Comment: I would have the text say something like `"Quarter with most rainfall is " + quarter + " with rainfall (actual):"`

Comment: I just edited his example. Not too interested in dressing it up for him.

Comment: so, if i do this way, it is always saying that quarter 4 is the max and min, no matter if quarter might have the most rainfall. Any idea on to store the correct variable in i?

Comment: You're doing something wrong then. I just tested it. It worked fine for my example (added to the answer).

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out.  I left a set of brackets out of the if statement.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't forget to a) sign up b) tick the answer c) try to answer some yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You should format your code (Ctrl+Shift+f in Eclipse).

Keep the `i` index in parallel to the min and max, something like imax, imin. Otherwise you lose the origin of the values like in your case.