# How to Sort a 2D array based on 1D array

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So i have something like this

> 011 -   50
>   111  -  75
>   001   - 25

This is my program :

```
public class Urut {
public void Sort (int [][] input1,int[] input2){
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 10-1; k++){
              if (input2[k] > input2[k+1]){
            int t;
                t = input1[k][i]; 
                input1[k][i] = input1[k+1][i]; 
                input1[k+1][i] = t; 
            }
        }
    }
 }
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10-1; j++){
        if (input2[j] > input2[j+1]){
                int te = input2[j];
                input2[j] = input2[j+1];
                input2[j+1] = te;
        }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< 5; j++){
            System.out.print(input1[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(" " + input2[i]);
    }
}
```

}

I want to sort the 2D array (the 0 and 1) based on the value on the right (which is a 1D array). Can someone help me?

Comment: How is the 1D array going to affect the order of the 2D array? What are your sorting rules?

Comment: ascending order. So the row on the 2D array will follow the sorted 1D array in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess!

It is not a `2D array` but it is a `map`. Ok, `2D array` with two rows. First row is like this:

`011, 111, 001`

and second is like this

`50, 75, 25`

You want to sort the first row, considering second row. So for your example, it will be:

`001, 011, 111` because of `25, 50, 75`

If I am right, an answer is here: [How to sort a Map on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109383/1021970)

If I am wrong, please add a comment, I will remove this answer.

---

**EDIT :**

[Java: Sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8938235/1021970)

Comment: no, it's 2 different arrays. the first one goes like this 
first row  011
second row 111
third row  001
i want to sort them based on the one other array which goes like this
first row  50
second row 75
third row  25
i want to make it something like this
001 - 25
011 - 50
111 - 75

Comment: ok. my hint for you is: put more code, explain your problem deeper

Comment: So, you have got 2 arrays. Sort 1st one, sort 2nd one. Done

Comment: i can't. that's my problem over there. my friend suggest me to use comparable or comparator but i just can't understand it for my problem

Comment: paste your code. **EDIT:** I edited my post, take a look