# I need to sort through an object array and order them highest to lowest

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am a student in a beginning java class, I got some help earlier today on my assignment, which really helped!  So I thought I would give it one more try, before I throw in the towel on this last part.  I have been able to get everything going, but my sort just doesn't work.  I have to use this format, as my professor does not want us to use sort APIs.  It processes correctly, meaning I get the same results by hand as when I run it, so I think the problem is in the logic itself.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and offer any hints or helps.  Thanks in advance.  Here is my code for my sort loop:

```
    int i, j; // used to index into the array
    double temp;

    for (i = 1; i < count ; ++i) {
        temp = students[i].getGPA();
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && temp < students[j].getGPA()) 
        {
            students[j + 1] = students[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        students[j + 1]= students[i];
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Sort an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array)

Comment: Thanks, I read that through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not doing the swapping correctly. Check this sample code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < students.length - i; j++)
             {
               if (students[j - 1].getGPA() > students[j].getGPA())
                {
                   // assuming that your class name is Student
                   Student temp = students[j - 1];
                   students[j - 1] = students[j];
                   students[j] = temp;
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Great! I used this way, at first it threw an error, but I just had to change the 2nd for loop to one less that students.length and it worked great.  Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the first iteration through the while loop overwrites students[i].  You need to keep students[i], and not just its GPA, in a temporary value when you enter the for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried that previously but I was having difficulty getting the data types to match up.  When I made temp an object like students[I], it would let me compare them with"<".  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Refined your logic little bit. Plz verify for appropriateness!

```
    package com.kvvssut.misc;

    public class SortArray {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double [] studentsGPA = {8.3,7.2,10,6.5,4.9};
            int count = studentsGPA.length;
            int i, j; // used to index into the array
            double temp;

            for (i = 1; i < count ; ++i) {
                j = i;
                while (j > 0 && (temp = studentsGPA[j]) < studentsGPA[--j]) {   // can use students[j].getGPA() similarly 
                    studentsGPA[j+1] = studentsGPA[j];
                    studentsGPA[j] = temp;
                }
            }

            for (double sgpa : studentsGPA ) {
                System.out.println(sgpa);
            }
        }

    }
```