# Need help on sorting an array -- a new programmer

Tags: java, arrays

I am just sorting an array and need some advice on the **sorting** and I also need help **printing** the array after I have sorted it. Also no, I do **not** want to use the Arrays utility.

Code:

```
package Sort;

public class SortCode {

    static int[] intArray = {
        12, 34, 99, 1, 89,
        39, 17, 8, 72, 68};
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    void printArray(int[] arrayInts) {
        System.out.println("Values before sorting:");
        System.out.println("Index" + "\tValue");

        for (; j < arrayInts.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(j + "\t" + arrayInts[j]);

        } //for (int j)

    } //void printArray

    void sortArray() {
      System.out.println("Values after sorting:");
      System.out.println("Index" + "\tValue");
       int i;
       int k;
        for (i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
          for (k = 0; k > intArray.length; k++) {
            if (intArray[i] > intArray[k]) {
                int firstNum = intArray[i];
                int secondNum = intArray[k];
                intArray[i] = secondNum;
                intArray[k] = firstNum;

            } //if

          } //for

        } //for

    } //void sortArray

} //class BranchCode
```

Comment: define "acting weird". What kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Debugging. Pretend you're the computer, line by line--it's a very easy error to find if you do that, deliberately, with attention. Also, I advocate against right-brace comments like that--instead, rely on indentation (I'd suggest 4 spaces) and limited nesting.

Answer (score 4):

Change sign **>** for **<** inside `for (k = 0; k > intArray.length; k++) {`

Probably it should help you

Comment: Ok, now how can I print out the array once it is sorted in sortArray

Comment: just iterate with for loop and println it

Comment: sorry for being a noob here but can you help me out with that.

Comment: printArray method is doing what you need, not the best way, but looks like it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to find different sorting implementation on mathbits http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Sorting.htm .

Here is better example of bubble sort .

```
public  void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might help as well [Java: Sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array)

**Example to use code**

public class SortExample {

```
int[] intArray = { 12, 34, 99, 1, 89, 39, 17, 8, 72, 68 };

public void printArray(int[] arrayInts) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayInts.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(j + "\t" + arrayInts[j]);

    } // for (int j)

} // void printArray

public void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void process() {

    System.out.println("Values before sorting:");
    System.out.println("Index \tValue");
    printArray(intArray);
    bubbleSort(intArray);
    System.out.println("Values after sorting:");
    System.out.println("Index" + "\tValue");
    printArray(intArray);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortExample example = new SortExample();
    example.process();
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, now what would be the println statement to printout the sorted array using this?

Comment: assuming I am calling the methods in following order
bubbleSort(intArray);
printArray(intArray);

Output will be as follows

Values before sorting:
Index Value
0 1
1 8
2 12
3 17
4 34
5 39
6 68
7 72
8 89
9 99

Comment: Well yeah but what would the System.out.println( what would go here to print sorted array)

Comment: you are already printing . 
      public void printArray(int[] arrayInts) {
    
      
          for (int j = 0; j < arrayInts.length; j++) {
              System.out.println(j + "\t" + arrayInts[j]);

          } 

      }

Comment: I want to print it twice, before its sorted and after. How can I print it after it is sorted in the sortCode method

Comment: Modify the your printArray method , remove the print line . something like this

System.out.println("Values before sorting:");
       System.out.println("Index \tValue");
    printArray(intArray);
    bubbleSort(intArray);
      System.out.println("Values after sorting:");
      System.out.println("Index" + "\tValue");

  printArray(intArray);