# Return a randomly generated sorted Array as a String. HOW?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a class that returns a String to the main method. The String is supposed to contain 6 randomly generated numbers from 1-99, and the numbers are supposed to be sorted before they are returned. However it doesn't work at all and I've been sitting all day trying to figure this out. I am new to Java and would prefer to just give it up but it's a class at my university. The code looks like this:

```
package lab1;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab111 {

    private String rad;

    public String getLottorad() {

        Random r = new Random();
        int[] tal = new int[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { //generating 6 numbers
             tal[i] = r.nextInt(99)+1;
        }
        int i,j,crap;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++) { //trying to sort the generated numbers
           for(j=i+1;j<100;j++) {
               if(tal[i]>tal[j]) {
                  crap=tal[i];
                  tal[i]=tal[j];
                  tal[j]=crap;                
               }
            }
         }
         rad = String.valueOf(tal[i]); /*trying to turn the sorted numbers into an int*/
        return rad;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("How many lottery lines do you want? :");
        Scanner tgb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int antal = tgb.nextInt();
        Lab111 l = new Lab111();
        for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++)
            System.out.println(l.getLottorad()); // printing the sorted strings 
    }
}
```

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong it would be really appreciated. Me and a classmate that is on my level have been tearing our hair off all day.

Comment: Love the attitude :) Stack Overflow is the place we all go when we give up. You're in the right place.

Comment: Just a hint: try to make the sorting more generic - probably move it to a separate method and allow input-arrays of arbitrary size. Carefully reading and **understanding** the error-message you get might help quite a bit aswell.

Comment: This is basically everything you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array If not, you should specify you need to do the sorting yourself.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generate a list of six random values.  You appear to understand this.
2. Sort the list.  Consider the Collections.sort method.
3. Loop through the list (consider the java for each construct) and build a comma separated list of values (read [Apache Commons Lang 3 StrBuffer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrBuilder.html), pay attention to appendSeparator).
4. return StrBuffer.toString();

Note: a list is not an array.  read [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the lottery with a quite more work using arrays, instead I will suggest to use collections.

## What you need:

1. define a set because you dont want to generate duplicated numbers
2. add some random numbers to the set until the size of the collection is 6
3. now create a list from that set, we need this because list are sortable
4. sort the list
5. print it

---

## Final Snippet:

```
Set<Integer> randomSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
while (randomSet.size() < 6) {
    randomSet.add(r.nextInt(99) + 1);
}

List<Integer> listRandom = new ArrayList<Integer>(randomSet);
Collections.sort(listRandom);
System.out.println(listRandom);
```

---

## The Result:

6 Random numbers between 1 and 99, with no duplicates, sorted. :)

> [23, 43, 54, 86, 95, 98]

Answer (score 1):

To put the numbers into one string:

```
    String rad="";
    for(int i=0;i<tal.length;i++){
        rad+=tal[i] + ", ";
    }
    return rad;
```

Sorting is discussed at length here: [Java: Sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array)

Comment: Thanks guys! Really appreciate your input. From your tips I think I can make sense of the code and might get it to work. I will try out all of your tips tomorrow. Had to take a few beers to clear my head so won't be doing any more codewriting today. :) But my dearest thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sorted output from an `Array` of six randomly generated `Integer`s this way by using a `List` and including the `Collections` and `Arrays` classes

Add these import statements:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
```

---

```
    Random r = new Random();
    Integer[] tal = new Integer[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {//generating 6 numbers
        tal[i] = r.nextInt(99)+1;
    }

    List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(tal); // convert Array to List

    Collections.sort(integerList); // Sort list

    String rad = String.valueOf(integerList); // convert list to String

    return rad;
```

By modifying your code and creating a `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Integer[] tal = new Integer[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {//generating 6 numbers
        tal[i] = r.nextInt(99)+1;
    }

    List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(tal); // convert Array to List

    Collections.sort(integerList); // Sort list

    String rad = String.valueOf(integerList); // convert list to String

    System.out.println(rad);
}
```

I am able to get the following output:

> [27, 42, 58, 67, 79, 89]

You can further optimize your code by never using an `Array` and just using a `List` to begin with.

This is what that optimization would look like.

```
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {//generating 6 numbers
        integerList.add(r.nextInt(99)+1);
    }

    Collections.sort(integerList); // Sort list

    String rad = String.valueOf(integerList); // convert list to String

    return rad;
```

In order for this optimized solution to work you'll have to import `ArrayList`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```