# Countdown timer rearrangement in android

Tags: android, arrays, countdowntimer

i am getting multiple items having countdown timers from back end and i am storing those in array list. I want to rearrange them according to decreasing order. Please help me, i am stuck.

Comment: Add your relevant code first.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, i am new to it. Basically i am getting list of countdown timers from backend. I am saving those in arraylist, and setting up adapter. I want to show timers whose value is more than 30 seconds to show at first. How to sort them all.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to sort into an array... see: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/sorting_arrays.html
and/or:
[Java: Sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array)
and/or: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=sort+in+array+java

The instruction which can help you to sort an array is:

```
Arrays.sort(your_array,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

for a list

```
Collections.sort(list ,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

for an array

```
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```