# how to find length till specific value in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

In a number of array i need length till max value without using sort and

> {6,8,2,7,10,3,1}

is it possible to return max-first minimum is that array(10-2=8)?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. In your example `(10-2=8)` where does the 2 comes from ? is 10 the max value of the array ? is 8 from `array[1]` or it's completely different ? do you need the index until the max value  (here it should be 5)?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for it is the function *Array.short*, you can do that:

```
/*Code not tested*/
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(array[0]); //min value
System.out.println(array[array.length-1]); //max value
```

You can see more about this function here: [Java: Sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/java-sort-an-array)

**Edit**

If you can't sort you can use a algorithm here a good example http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/bubble-sort/

Comment: @Rishi Thanks is true I'm through the cell phone, sorry.

Comment: @DanteFañaBadia without using sort i need 10-2 not 10-1

Comment: @Digs well you can use System.out.println(array[1]); , but the code will be very specific and useless and if you have 2 "1" doesn't work.

Comment: @DanteFañaBadia ik but it should pass all test cases

Comment: @Digs use sort algorithm  here a example http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code uses [IntStream#summaryStatistics()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--):

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(intArray).summaryStatistics();
int maxDiff = stats.getMax() - stats.getMin();
```

This approach has O(n) time complexity, which is better than O(n log n) time complexity of sorting the array.

There are faster O(n) algorithms that *just* calculate the max diff, but this approach is probably good enough for most purposes.