# Sorting values off array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to this site and new to java so pleas help me out. If i have array of positive and negative numbers all are int,
how to sort all the positive ones in a new array and all negative in a other new array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](//stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/sort-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Asking a question in StackOverflow without any selfstudy on basics would attract downvotes. Kindly take time in doing your research. However to make you understand the way to solve I am providing you with a solution.

Step 1: You have an array of positive and negative values

```
Integer[] initialArray = new Integer[10];
```

//This contains the list of all values.

Step 2: Create two ArrayLists to save the negative and positive values in each of these.

```
ArrayList<Integer> positiveValues = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> negativeValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

Step 3: Iterate through **initialArray** and save the respective values in both lists.

```
for(int i =0; i< initialArray.length; i++) {
  if(initialArray[i] < 0) {
    negativeValues.add(initialArray[i]);
  } else {
    positiveValues.add(initialArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Step 4: Now sort the values

```
Collections.sort(negativeValues);
Collections.sort(positiveValues);
```

Step 5: **If Required** If you need in arrays instead of ArrayList,

```
Integer[] negativeArray = new Integer[negativeValues.size()];
Integer[] positiveArray = new Integer[positiveValues.size()];
```

And cast these to get the array

Comment: Not quite right... you cannot sort Collection classes with `java.util.Arrays`. You'd have to use `java.util.Collections` for that.

Comment: That is is. I do rly close to this. TY m8 and sorry my first time here. Cheers

Comment: Yeah.. thanks for the catch

Comment: `final Integer[] positives = positiveValues.toArray(new Integer[0]);`is much easier^^

Comment: OP should clarify where `0` goes, if anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this is a pretty good question.  Here is an implementation you can try using Java 8 streams.

Given an integer array full of mixed negative/positive numbers:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 4, -2, 5, -9, 2 };
```

One solution could be as follows:

```
int[] pos = Arrays.stream(a).filter(i -> i >= 0).sorted().toArray();
int[] neg = Arrays.stream(a).filter(i -> i < 0).sorted().toArray();
```

The pos[] array will have all the positive numbers sorted, and neg[] all the negative numbers sorted.  The only thing I really dislike is that a[] is traversed twice, but at least it is short.

Comment: Thx I will do all of this ways so its rly helpful for my progress.

Answer (score -1):

First seperate positive and negative numbers. I mean find size of positive numbers and create-set new positive numbers array. Then find size of negative numbers and create-set new negative numbers array.

Then just call sort method on both arrays.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Comment: Why was this voted down!? He also could have used Collections for this, but this is a legit answer, and seeing that Paojepablo wants us to do his homework, the length of that answer was also good. So why the downvote?

Comment: I need to make a logic that will move all positive values in new array and all negative in another new array

Comment: @JayC667: The problem is that while the asker asks for a way to "sort" his array in reality he wants to seperate positive and negative numbers into two seperate arrays.

Comment: I was not talking about downvoting Paojepablo's question, but hellzone's answer. His answer was perfect... not too much to do Paojepablo's homework, enough to give an overview...

Comment: Bro i didnt and cant vote down on him coz i am new, and i dont see his answer voted down at all. Why not help and just flame. True its for homework but its just a prat i was stuck on coz i am new to this. Plz dont heat i write i am new and all...