# Q: Sorting of Numeric array in java

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a numeric array in ascending and descending order. I am beginner so using the following link [Sort an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/sort-an-array-in-java) . I am trying to get input from user as array's elements.

```
public class SortingofString {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int Array1[];
 //   String Array2[];
    System.out.println("How many numaric elements: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[] array1 = new int[n];
    int number=input.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
       array1[i] = number;
        System.out.println("Original numeric array : "+Arrays.toString(Array1));
        Arrays.sort(Array1);
        System.out.println("Sorted numeric array : "+Arrays.toString(Array1));


    } 
}
}
```

The error occurs when i pass my array_name `Array1` in first `toString` function.
`System.out.println("Original numeric array : "+Arrays.toString(Array1));` 

 Error says **Initialize variable** **`Array1`** . How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int Array1[];     
    System.out.println("How many numaric elements: ");

    int n = input.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];// solve 1st problem
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter number: " +(i+1));
        int number = input.nextInt();
        arr[i]=number;//init  array  by user input data
    }
    System.out.println("Original numeric array : " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println("Sorted numeric array : " + Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

you also need 2 import

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: Yes i have added these libraries

Answer (score 0):

Move (and rename) `Array1` behind reading `n`:

```java
System.out.println("How many numaric elements: ");
int n = input.nextInt();
int[] array1 = new int[n];
```

And maybe *use* the entered `number`:

```java
int number = input.nextInt();
array1[i] = number;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code as it is now. What error do you get?

Comment: You did not change your code like I wrote above. Remove the line containing `int Array1[];` and change every occurenc of `Array1` to `array1`.

Comment: according to another answer i have changed my code and it is working. Thank u so much @Lutz Horn

Comment: Yes i have understand  @Lutz Horn. You are right i changed my array name Array1 to arr