# Java sorting array with strings

Tags: java

Hey I have this project where the program displays team scores in a descending order but the problem is I can't switch up the team names so they can be in order because the team names array is a string.

```
 for(int i = 0;i<tabPTS.length;i++){ // tabEquipe is the array containing the team names.
       for (int j = i+1; j<tabPTS.length;j++){
           if(tabPTS[i]<tabPTS[j]){
               temp = tabPTS[i];
               tabPTS[i] = tabPTS[j];
               tabPTS[j] = temp;
           }
       }
   }
     System.out.println("Equipes: ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("\t" + "PJ");
    System.out.print("\t" + "V");
    System.out.print("\t" +  "D");
    System.out.print("\t" +  "PTS");
    System.out.println();
   for(int i = 0;i<tabPTS.length;i++){
        int pos = i;

        System.out.println(tabEquipe[i] + "\t" +   tabPJ[i] + "\t"
                + tabVict[i] + "\t" +  tabDef[i] + "\t" + tabPTS[i]); 

   }
```

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938235/sort-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you want to output team names and their scores in sorted order based on their scores.
Multiple ways to approach this problem:

1) Try defining a type to hold team name and their score together and then sort an array of such objects based on their score.

2) If you have to keep scores and team names as separate arrays, keep switching the values in the team names array along with the scores array in your selection sort algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To sort a String array in Java, you need to compare each element of the array to all the remaining elements, if the result is greater than 0, swap them.

One solution to do so you need to use two loops (nested) where the inner loop starts with i+1 (where i is the variable of outer loop) to avoid repetitions in comparison.

Here Is the Example

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringArrayInOrder {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String[] myArray = {"JavaFX", "HBase", "OpenCV", "Java", "Hadoop", "Neo4j"};
      int size = myArray.length;

      for(int i = 0; i<size-1; i++) {
         for (int j = i+1; j<myArray.length; j++) {
            if(myArray[i].compareTo(myArray[j])>0) {
               String temp = myArray[i];
               myArray[i] = myArray[j];
               myArray[j] = temp;
            }
         }
      }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
   }
}
```

Here is The output of above code

```
[HBase, Hadoop, Java, JavaFX, Neo4j, OpenCV]
```

You can also sort an array using the **`sort()`** method of the **Arrays** class.

Like this

```
String[] myArray = {"JavaFX", "HBase", "OpenCV", "Java", "Hadoop","Neo4j"};
Arrays.sort(myArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

You can Sorts `arr[]` in descending order like this

```
String arr[] = {"p","q","c"}; 

// Sorts arr[] in ascending order 
        Arrays.sort(arr); 
        System.out.printf("Modified arr[] : \n%s\n\n", 
                          Arrays.toString(arr)); 

        // Sorts arr[] in descending order 
        Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

And output

```
Modified arr[] : 


Modified arr[] : 
[q, p, c]
```